# how to remove component from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

OK.  Inserting a component programatically is obvious: `myJTextPane.insertComponent`.

Accessing components was a little trickier, but I use something like: `myJTextPane.getComponents().getComponents()[0]`. (1)

But how do I remove a component programatically from myJTextPane?

(1) I am actually programming in Clojure, so the syntax may not be 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You treat it as a character at a specific position:

```
myJTextPane.getDocument().remove(int offs, int len)
```

For example if you have a text pane with components in this order:

[Component1] - [Component2] - [Component3] - some text

and you want to remove 2nd and 3rd components:

```
myJTextPane.getDocument().remove(1, 2)
```

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#remove%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: It is quick-and-dirty.  It doesn't take into conciseration that the user might have typed characters into the field as well. But it is good enough for now.  Thanks.