# Get a component from a JTextPane through javax.swing.text.Element?

Tags: java, swing, element, jtextpane, jcomponent

I am using a `JTextPane` to display characters and symbols, where the latter are represented by custom painted `JComponents`. For example, the text pane might show something like this:
[image]
The text pane is user editable and it is allowed for the user to add more symbols via a button at any position and as a replacement for selected text. I do this via the `JTextPane.insertComponent()` method. At some point in the application I need to know what is currently being displayed in the text pane, and by that I mean not only the entered text, but also the exact components contained within.

I went through extensive troubles with `Positions` and `DocumentListeners` to manage the content of my text pane, but I kept causing more problems than I was solving. That is why I finally decided, that my troubles are probably due to a design fault on my part, so I decided to see, if I can't get to my components through the text pane.

Searching through the documentation and the source code of `AbstractDocument` and other related classes, I found the interface `javax.swing.text.Element`. I then let my application output

```
for(int i = 0; i < textPane.getDocument().getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(((StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument()).getCharacterElement(i));
}
```

which gave me:

> LeafElement(content) 0,4
>
> LeafElement(content) 0,4
>
> LeafElement(content) 0,4
>
> LeafElement(content) 0,4
>
> LeafElement(component) 4,5
>
> LeafElement(content) 5,9
>
> LeafElement(content) 5,9
>
> LeafElement(content) 5,9
>
> LeafElement(content) 5,9
>
> LeafElement(component) 9,10

Seeing that the `LeafElements` that I got do seem to have some kind of information about what is displayed at which position in the `Document`, I figured that it must be possible to get the actual content at that position. After searching for another half hour how to get the content each of the elements represent, I gave up and decided to post my question here, hoping that some of you might know how to accomplish this!?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859751/how-to-remove-component-from-jtextpane?rq=1) where someone tries to access the components through `textPane.getComponents()`, which returns an array of components with the exact number of components actually contained in the `JTextPane`, but they are all of the type `javax.swing.text.ComponentView$Invalidator`, which is obviously of no use to me. Maybe I just don't see how to properly continue from here, because a cast to the original type of my symbol doesn't work.

**tl;dr**

How do I get a `JComponent`, which is inside the text of a `JTextPane`, and its position from the text pane?

Comment: Hopefully, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463120/1057230), might can help in providing some idea regarding the positioning thingy. +1 for more attention :-)

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali Thank you for the attention :-). Your answer is interesting, but unfortunately it doesn't apply to my problem, because I don't need to know the `Location` of the component, but rather the position as-in: index within the text. All of that is useless though, if I cannot access the component itself, which is absolutely necessary to my aim.

Comment: Ahha, this knowledge is beyond my grasp, as yet. Wish someone with wisdom, be able to put light on the topic real soon :-) BEST OF LUCK...

Comment: ***[This](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/24786-insert-retrieve-embedded-buttons-jtextpanel.html)*** post might be of help.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders That did in fact help. That way I can access all of my components properly. I cannot fully accept this as an answer yet, because of two reasons: 1. you didn't post it as an answer and 2. I cannot get the position of each component this way, or can I? (And by position, I mean not `Location` but rather index.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can traverse the text pane's `StyledDocument` to find elements that represent components or icons, as shown below.

[image]

```
BranchElement(section) 0,7

BranchElement(paragraph) 0,7

LeafElement(content) 0,4

LeafElement(icon) 4,5

class javax.swing.plaf.IconUIResource
LeafElement(component) 5,6

class javax.swing.JLabel
LeafElement(content) 6,7
```

SSCCE:

```
/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15669307/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883413
 */
public class DocumentParse {

    private static final String ELEM = AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute;
    private static final String ICON = StyleConstants.IconElementName;
    private static final String COMP = StyleConstants.ComponentElementName;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) jtp.getDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet normal = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(normal, "Serif");
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(normal, 72);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(normal, Color.blue);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Test", normal);
        jtp.setSelectionStart(doc.getLength());
        jtp.insertIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
        jtp.setSelectionStart(doc.getLength());
        jtp.insertComponent(new JLabel("Label"));
        jtp.setSelectionStart(doc.getLength());

        ElementIterator iterator = new ElementIterator(doc);
        Element element;
        while ((element = iterator.next()) != null) {
            System.out.println(element);
            AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
            if (as.containsAttribute(ELEM, ICON)) {
                System.out.println(StyleConstants.getIcon(as).getClass());
            }
            if (as.containsAttribute(ELEM, COMP)) {
                System.out.println(StyleConstants.getComponent(as).getClass());
            }
        }

        f.add(jtp);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, THIS is the kind of answer I was looking for! I knew that it had to be possible to access everything in the `JTextPane` through `Elements`, I just couldn't figure out how. Follow up questions: 1. How do I find out that I have to ask the `AttributeSet` for `StyleConstants.ComponentElementName`, I mean how do I know where to look for this kind of string constants? 2. Why does the `ElementIterator` give me a new line character after the document's contents? (I get `LeafElement(content) 12,13` even though `textPane.getDocument.getLength()` yields `12`!)

Comment: @SheridanVespo: 1. Honestly, I enumerated `getAttributeNames()` and searched the API for the named constants. 2. Courtesy of `AbstractDocument#toString()`.

Comment: 1. Thanks, maybe that will help me with future problems I have.  2.`AbstractDocument` does not have a `toString()` method!? At least not according to [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.java#AbstractDocument).

Comment: @SheridanVespo: Ah, `AbstractDocument.BranchElement#toString()`; I put a breakpoint in `element.toString()` to see.

Comment: But that function does `return "BranchElement(" + getName() + ") " + getStartOffset() + "," + getEndOffset() + "\n";` So, that does imho not explain the additional `LeafElement` at the end!?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the extra _newline_. Note that "`AbstractDocument` models an implied break at the end of the document."

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. I meant the extra _new line character_ which is what is appended to the content.

Answer (score 4):

The original component is the first (and only) child of the `javax.swing.text.ComponentView$Invalidator` as you can see from ComponentView.

You can get list of the invalidators and use their children to acccess inserted components.

Comment: See ComponentView's sources. In fact on layout view action setComponentParent is called. It has the code    void setComponentParent() {
 View p = getParent();
 if (p != null) {
     Container parent = getContainer();
     if (parent != null) {
  if (c == null) {
      // try to build a component
      Component comp = createComponent();
      if (comp != null) {
   createdC = comp;
   c = new Invalidator(comp);
      }
  }