# Understanding the use of Elements in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, element, jtextarea

I'm working on a project that requires having low level control over text that will be displayed in a JTextArea. In my search to understand how this can be achieved I came across Elements. Is there any way using custom Elements that I could get access to the individual words typed into a document? If so, how would I structure these elements?

Comment: you want space separate words of TextArea?

Comment: Yes. However, I am not interested in reading the entire text every time it is modified and running a regex over it. Rather, I am wondering if it is possible to get what are effectively 'hooks' to the words in the text. That way I could access and modify these words without having a parse the entire body of text.

Comment: `jtextArea.getText()` ?

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for. getText offers up a copy of the entire text contained in the textArea. I'd like to have hooks to individual words without having ever get the entire document's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to have hooks to individual words

Maybe `Document.createPosition()`

Comment: This is what I ended up using as a hacky solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An instance of [`javax.swing.text.Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) represents a part of a structured [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html), the model used by `JTextComponent`. Elements are not necessarily individual words; they are typically parts of a document that share some common attribute(s). You can see how to traverse the elements of a document in examples shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669307/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883413/230513). See also [*How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).