# javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument getElement ByName

Tags: java, html, swing, parsing, dom

I am looking for ways to grab an element by name. I tried iterating one element at a time by using `Element.getAttributes.getAttributeNames()` and iterated through each element to find the name then checked it with the name I am looking for. Any alternatives or optimized way to grab the element directly?

Comment: Here's an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for reference: [`DocumentParse`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15669307/230513).

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I use to retrieve elements by tag name. For `mixed-content` elements (e.g., `sub`, `sup`, `b`, `i`), you need to look in the attributes of the “fake” `content` elements.

```
/**
 * Returns all elements of a particular tag name.
 *
 * @param tagName The tag name of the elements to return (e.g., HTML.Tag.DIV).
 * @param document The HTML document to find tags in.
 * @return The set of all elements in the HTML document having the specified tag name.
 */
public static Element[] getElementsByTagName(HTML.Tag tagName, HTMLDocument document)
{
    List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

    for (ElementIterator iterator = new ElementIterator(document); iterator.next() != null;)
    {
        Element currentEl = iterator.current();

        AttributeSet attributes = currentEl.getAttributes();

        HTML.Tag currentTagName = (HTML.Tag) attributes.getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);

        if (currentTagName == tagName)
        {
            elements.add(iterator.current());
        } else if (currentTagName == HTML.Tag.CONTENT) {
            for (Enumeration<?> e = attributes.getAttributeNames(); e.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                if (tagName == e.nextElement())
                {
                    elements.add(iterator.current());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return elements.toArray(new Element[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for ways to grab an element by name.

Perhaps you could use the [`getElement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#getElement%28java.lang.String%29) method? It takes as an argument the String value for the id of the element you are searching for.

Comment: i am aware of that but i am looking to do this document.getelementsbyname('name') in java

Comment: did you read the documentation for [javax.swing.text.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html)? it has the `document.getElement(name)` method. it should be the same thing as document.getelementsbyname('name').

Comment: i think there is a small miscommunication,
getElement(id) Returns the element that has the given id Attribute.
i am looking for getting elements by name attribute

Comment: Oh oops. I am not sure how to do that then...just ignore my answer haha